# React Router doesn't load images properly with nested routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

My route code looks like this:

```
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path='/' component={AppContainer}>
            <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
            <Route path='/MyRYLA' component={MyRYLA} />
            <Route path='/gallery' component={PhotoViewer}/>
            <Route path='/about' component={AboutView}>
                <IndexRoute component={AboutRYLA}/>
                <Route path='/about/contact' component={Contact}/>
                <Route path='/about/directions' component={Directions}/>
                <Route path='/about/principles' component={Principles}/>
                <Route path='/about/faq' component={FAQ}/>
            </Route>
        </Route>
    </Router>
```

I have an image that renders within `AboutView`, so that each page under `AboutView` still has that image on it. But every time I navigate to a nested URL like '/about/directions', using `browserHistory.push('/about/directions')`, the image doesn't load. However, if I navigate to just '/about' using `browserHistory.push('/about')`, the image does load.

I do get an error in the console that says `GET http://localhost:8080/about/af16977b21bb178d3bb328689d1ecd65.jpg 404 (Not Found)`. This looks to me like it is trying to get the image from a non-existent 'about' directory. How can I load the image and prevent React-Router from trying to access this image through a non-existent 'about' directory?

Answer (score 13):

Is is possible you're using a relative path in your image tag?

Something like `<img src="af16977b21bb178d3bb328689d1ecd65.jpg" />` instead of `<img src="/af16977b21bb178d3bb328689d1ecd65.jpg" />`

The inital`/` in the `src` attribute makes the image load from the root of the website.

Comment: I am requiring the images through an external images.js file, which is located at /dev/js/images.js. My html file is at /src/pages/index.html. I import the images through an array from images.js.

Comment: I can't believe the solution was this easy.  Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

This is what ended up helping me get my images to work with nested routes in React:

```
<head>
    <base href="/">
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the image link you're passing to it? Can you make it explicit? Ie `'http://....your link'`, don't make it relative.

Comment: I am requiring it using require('../../resources/ryla.jpg');

Comment: Are your components/pages in other files inside about directory? You would have to require in those too, I guess you are doing that, but with the same path? You have to change that to ../../../resources/ryla.jpg in there.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your using webpack?

```
//require the image
let img = require("/img.jpg") //the static path which you've defined in you webpack.config

// And see to it your plugins are set correctly to read the image files
// webpack.config.js

module.exports = {
    module: {
        loaders: [{ test: /\.(jpe?g|gif|png|svg)$/, loader: "file" }]
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have the correct loaders, and the images load properly when I route to a _non-nested_ route, like '/about'